# ng-if only first directive working with self-closing tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, angular-ng-if

I am new to angular, so this may not be the best way to do this.  I will probably redo most of what I've already done as I learn more.

I am using url routing with `ngRoute` an it works fine.  In one of the pages, I then have a number of ng-include templates- again, everything is good.

In one of the `ng-include` templates, I am using two `directives` to display templates.

```
<provider-search providers="practiceData.providers" states="ref.states" specialties="ref.specialties" status="updateSearchStatus" ng-show="searchStatus == 1"/>
<search-list status="updateSearchStatus" addp="addProvider" providers="searchResults" ng-if="searchStatus == 2" />
```

Each of the directives uses isolated scope and a controller.  The problem is only the first directive is working.  If I switch the order, then the second directive (now if first position) works.  In short, only the directive listed first works.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You not closing the tag.

```
<provider-search providers="practiceData.providers" states="ref.states" specialties="ref.specialties" status="updateSearchStatus" ng-show="searchStatus == 1">
</provider-search>

<search-list status="updateSearchStatus" addp="addProvider" providers="searchResults" ng-if="searchStatus == 2">
</search-list>
```

**Why it is not working?**

> self-closing or void elements as the html spec defines them are very special to the browser parser. you can't make your own, so for your custom elements you have to stick to non-void elements (`<foo></foo>`).

Read more from here [self closing tag issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  After banging my head against a wall for a couple of hours, I eventually saw that in the documentation.